# How can I read values from a configuration file (text)?

Tags: rebol, red

I need to read values (text) from a configuration file named `.env` and assign them to variables so I can use them later in my program.

The `.env` file contains name/value pairs and looks something like this:

```
ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_ONE = AC9157847d72b1aa5370fdef36786863d9
ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_TWO = 73cad721b8cad6718d469acc42ffdb1f
ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_THREE = +13335557777
```

---

***What I have tried so far***

`read-values.red`

```
Red [

]

contents: read/lines %.env

env-one: first contents
env-two: second contents
env-three: third contents

print env-one ; ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_ONE = AC9157847d72b1aa5370fdef36786863d9
print env-two ; ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_ONE = 73cad721b8cad6718d469acc42ffdb1f
print env-three ; ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_ONE = +13335557777
```

---

***What I'm looking for***

```
print env-one ; AC9157847d72b1aa5370fdef36786863d9
print env-two ; 73cad721b8cad6718d469acc42ffdb1f
print env-three ; +13335557777
```

How do I continue or change my code and parse these strings such as the `env-` variables will contain just the values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`env-one: skip find first contents " = " 3`

See help for find and skip

Comment: Perfect, it works, thank you very much. Could you recommend a link for the help?

Comment: Red is largely Rebol-compatible, so [Rebol 3 docs](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions.html) may help you. Have a nice coding day! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Another solution using `parse` could be:

`foreach [word value] parse read %.env [collect some [keep to "=" skip keep to newline skip]] [set load word trim value]`

This one will add the words to the global context `ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_ONE` will be `AC9157847d72b1aa5370fdef36786863d9` and so on.

Comment: Instead of adding words to default context here is another version that returns a `map!` value: https://gist.github.com/endo64/e1c0f0db9b287e2e1392604f79d9f3fd

Also `[keep to "=" skip keep to [newline | end] skip]` could be better as above version doesn't work if there is no newline at the end.